# What's wrong with this simple trigger?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a Poll table

```
Poll(id, number_of_questions)
```

which contains information about polls and the number of question each poll has in it.

I have a Question table

```
Question(id, text)
```

And then I have a Composition table

```
Composition(poll, question)
```

poll references Poll.id and question references Question.id

As you can tell, this last table contains the associations between each poll and its questions.

I made a trigger which should increment

```
number_of_questions
```

after every INSERT on Composition

```
CREATE FUNCTION increment() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
UPDATE poll SET number_of_questions = number_of_questions + 1 WHERE poll.id = composition.poll;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
CREATE TRIGGER incrementQuestionNumber
AFTER INSERT ON composition FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE increment();
```

So, let's say I create a new Question having id = 3 and text = 'How are you'?

```
Question(3, 'How are you')
```

Then I associate this question to the poll having id = 5 with an insert in the composition table, resulting in this record being created in the composition table

```
Composition(5, 3)
```

After this insert the trigger should increment the number_of_questions in the Poll table where poll.id = 5.

In reality however, when I try to do that insert on Composition, it fails (the new record is not added) and i get

```
ERROR: FROM element in table "composition" is missing
```

What's wrong with the trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to use composition table in your trigger , the current composition's record is the variable "NEW". so in your trigger replace :

```
     UPDATE poll SET number_of_questions = number_of_questions + 1 WHERE poll.id = composition.poll;
```

by :

```
   UPDATE poll SET number_of_questions = number_of_questions + 1 WHERE poll.id = NEW.poll;
```

Comment: Ah! That's what I was missing!

Thanks a lot!